# KeyListener will not respond to keyboard input

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, mouselistener

I am trying to add a JPanel to a JFrame. The JPanel is supposed to listen to keyboard input and mouse input. When i open the window it does work for the mouse but the keyboard gets ignored and i just can't see the problem, since i wrote the same stuff for both Listeners.

This is the code for the Panel

```
public class testjpanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener,KeyListener {
    
    testjpanel (){
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

and here is the rest

```
public class main extends JFrame {
                
    public main() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500,500);
                    this.setVisible(true);
                    this.setLayout(null);
                            
                    testjpanel a= new testjpanel();     
                    a.setVisible(true);
                    a.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
                    a.setLayout(null);
                    
                    this.add(a);
                    
    }
}
```

Comment: `.setLayout(null);` is usually bad idea. Anyway `JPanel` is not focusable by default. You need to explicitly enable it, consider adding `this.setFocusable(true);` in `testjpanel` constructor. After that you can also add `this.grabFocus();` to *place* keyboard cursor there. BTW `setVisible(true);` should be called when all GUI is already set, not before.

Comment: Also, favor use of [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over KeyListeners.